# Interpretation of second character

Tags: characters, place-names

Here's a picture I have found on flickr, taken in an outdoor museum in South Korea. 
I can only recognize the 1st, 3rd and 4th characters: 寶X山房. 寶 is probably not the variant written on the wooden board, but it's the same character. What is the 2nd character?

The original high resolution image is [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/koreanet/17076171307/in/dateposted/).

[image]

EDIT： My best guess is 丁, but why this odd curvy shape when the rest of the characters are rendered fairly standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is indeed 丁. The Flickr link mentioned the photo was taken at 茶山草堂. With that information, I was able to find [another site](http://huanqiu21.blog.163.com/blog/static/186285415201182103713744/) with a photo of the same doorway indicating that it says 寶丁山房.

I don't know the specific reason why the character is stylized in this way, though 茶山 refers to the pen name of [Joeng Yak-yong (丁若鏞)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeong_Yak-yong), so it could be in reference to his surname, 丁.

Answer (score 1):

If [this blog](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_7f09352f0100yxc1.html) and [that](http://cluster1.cafe.daum.net/_c21_/bbs_search_read?grpid=1KcCH&fldid=JnFm&datanum=194&openArticle=true&docid=1KcCHJnFm19420110130230935) are correct, these four characters are indeed 寶丁山房, penned by the famous Korean calligrapher [Kim Jeong-hui 金正喜](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jeong-hui) in memory of 丁若鏞.

The characters on this wooden board look like 隸書 calligraphy to me. Please compare with the 隸書 section in the calligraphy samples of [寶](http://shufa.supfree.net/raky.asp?zi=%B1%A6), [丁](http://shufa.supfree.net/raky.asp?zi=%B6%A1), [山](http://shufa.supfree.net/raky.asp?zi=%C9%BD), and [房](http://shufa.supfree.net/raky.asp?zi=%B7%BF) respectively. It seems like Kim is being creative with the 丁 character here. I don't know much about Kim's style but thanks to this [google books search](https://books.google.com/books?id=FjlwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=%E9%87%91%E6%AD%A3%E5%96%9C%20%E6%9B%B8%E6%B3%95&source=bl&ots=ZrjWdoXdla&sig=ZOTX2VSmBGmyBLUpF0bEPNsJfsY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=heaUVbugG8OoogSH4JQQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%E9%87%91%E6%AD%A3%E5%96%9C%20%E6%9B%B8%E6%B3%95&f=false) I found out a bit more about his creative style.

[image]